# Storybook Cannot Find .ttf, .otf, .png, .svg, .jpg modules from create-react-app

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, storybook

I am working with Storybook and trying to get it to load with typescript, I've followed [this tutorial](https://storybook.js.org/configurations/typescript-config/) and I started with a **create-react-app** and ran **getstorybook** within the project. I am confused as to why storybook isn't aware of my webpack setup from create react app.

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/design-system/theme.ts:4:27 
    TS2307: Cannot find module './fonts/Futura-LT-Regular.ttf'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/design-system/theme.ts:5:24 
    TS2307: Cannot find module './fonts/Futura-LT-Bold.ttf'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/design-system/theme.ts:6:30 
    TS2307: Cannot find module './fonts/Caslon-Pro-Regular.otf'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/design-system/Icons.tsx:2:26 
    TS2307: Cannot find module './icons/pulse-logo.svg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/design-system/Form.tsx:3:24 
    TS2307: Cannot find module './icons/icon-pencil.svg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/design-system/Loaders.tsx:1:24 
    TS2307: Cannot find module './images/loading.gif'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/dashboard-components/OnboardingIntroduction.tsx:5:23 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../design-system/icons/signature.svg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/dashboard-components/OnboardingLaunchProcess.tsx:6:21 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../design-system/icons/map.svg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/dashboard-components/OnboardingLaunchProcess.tsx:7:26 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../design-system/icons/bulls-eye.svg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/dashboard-components/OnboardingLaunchProcess.tsx:8:23 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../design-system/icons/globe.svg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/dashboard-components/OnboardingLaunchProcess.tsx:9:22 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../design-system/icons/horn.svg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/dashboard-components/OnboardingLaunchProcess.tsx:10:24 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../design-system/icons/rocket.svg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/dashboard-components/OnboardingMarketingCollaterals.tsx:5:18 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../design-system/images/mutc.jpg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/dashboard-components/OnboardingMarketingCollaterals.tsx:6:27 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../design-system/images/resident-guide.jpg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/dashboard-components/OnboardingMarketingCollaterals.tsx:7:31 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../design-system/images/training-materials.jpg'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/dashboard-components/OnboardingMarketingCollaterals.tsx:8:18 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../design-system/images/swag.jpg'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to fix this my removing all node_modules and then installing them again.